# How to add a Method in String Class - C#

Tags: c#, string, methods, extension-methods, static-methods

I wish to add a following method `IsProcess(string str)` under String Class

For Exmaple `String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)`

```
public bool IsProcess(string str)
{
    bool flag = false;

    // LOGICS

    retrun flag;
}
```

I don't expect solution in terms of extension method like `"Value".IsProcess()`

```
public static bool IsProcess(this string str)
{
    bool flag = false;

    // LOGICS

    retrun flag;
}
```

> My Expectation is `String.IsProcess(value)`

Kindly assist me.

Comment: please look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Without extension method, it might not be possible. Also, `String` class is **sealed** , So you can't extend it.

Comment: You cannot add arbitrary static methods to classes. There's no such capability. You could "add" instance methods to objects via extension methods... but that's a completely different thing.

Comment: c# doesn't provide features like javascript prototype, also string class is sealed and you can't create wrapper from it.

Comment: If it's a static method you want, what does it matter if it is in this or that class? C# won't let you add a static method to a type in another assembly like System.String.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the only way to add a member _to_ a type is to edit the code for the type. Anything else is creating a member of another type but _could_ involve the original type via subtyping or extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't

You can create extension methods.  Other than that, it is not possible to add an additional static member to System.String.